# Gwenview Doesn't Have Option to Not Show Videos?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.04, gwenview

I'm using Gwenview that comes with Kubuntu 19.04 and it doesn't appear to have the option to not show videos anymore. (Videos play when browsing images using the arrow keys)

[image: Picture]

This was present in the toolbar which seems to have been removed in the latest release.

Is there some other way of disabling playing videos in gwenview like a configuration file?

Comment: Did you try `Settings` -> `Configure Gwenview` -> `General` -> `Uncheck video`? https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdegraphics/gwenview/configure.html#configindex

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix But there isn't a menu bar, nor is there any settings button on the left side.

Comment: Sorry Sarah I don't know where System Settings are in KDE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is still there and in the same place as it is in 18.04: *Settings > Configure Gwenview > General*.

[image: Toggle "Show videos"]

To deal with "But there isn't a menu bar", pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will toggle the menu bar on or off in Gwenview.

---

Tip:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> does something similar in Dolphin. It toggles the menu bar and the *Control* icon (☰) which offers the same options but in a vertical format.

To toggle the menu's visibility in Konsole, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for digging me out of that KDE hole :)

Comment: You're most welcome. You got it right but there was the complication of the toggled menu bar. Too many customization options  ;)